# strftime is printing same date format instead of new date when used with events of top level window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get date format when ever user changes it in system OS, but I am getting the same date.

I have code like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <time.h>   /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime, strftime */
#include <locale.h> /* struct lconv, setlocale, localeconv */
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

const TCHAR g_szClassName[] = TEXT("myWindowClass");

int getDate() {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  char system_date_buffer[80];
  char iso_date_buffer[80];
  int date_format;

  struct lconv *lc;

  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  strftime(system_date_buffer, 80, "%x", timeinfo);
  printf("System Date format is: %s\n", system_date_buffer);
  strftime(iso_date_buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%d", timeinfo);
  printf("ISO Date format is: %s\n", iso_date_buffer);
  return puts(iso_date_buffer);
  return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (msg) {
  case WM_SETTINGCHANGE: {
    getDate();
    cout << "event received - lParam: " << (char *)lParam << endl;

  } break;
  case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  WNDCLASSEX wc;
  HWND hwnd;
  MSG Msg;

  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.style = 0;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
  wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
  wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
  wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

  if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Registration Failed!"), _T("Error!"),
               MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
  }

  hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName,
                        _T("The title of my window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120, NULL, NULL,
                        hInstance, NULL);

  if (hwnd == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Window Creation Failed!"), _T("Error!"),
               MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
  }

  // ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);

  while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
  }
  return Msg.wParam;
}
```

When ever the event is triggered and case is matched here, I am calling `getDate()` method:

```
case WM_SETTINGCHANGE: {
     getDate(); // prints same date value
     cout << "event received - lParam: " << (char *)lParam << endl;
}
```

But it prints same date format. Why? The variables such as `struct tm *timeinfo;` is created every time the method is called I guess so Why it is not printing new date format?

Comment: Please don't tag C++ code as C.

Comment: Does `setlocale()` override the user settings?

Comment: @tad The code that's failing is C code. The only C++ code is for printing diagnostics.

Comment: This is *all* C++ code since you have `using namespace std` and use `cout` in it. This will not compile in C. Just tag it as C++ since that's what it is. C++ includes C-style code by definition since it is generally a superset of C.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use formatting strings that are based on info obtained from `GetLocaleInfo()` directly, instead of using `setlocale()`? Such as `LOCALE_SLONGDATE`

Comment: @tadman `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` sets the default locale that is there in current system. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/

Comment: @tadman `strftime` and `locale.h` is based on C only right - not c++?

Comment: This will *only* compile in C++ mode. Just tag it as C++ and you'll get the right attention. If this was pure C code you would tag it as C if you prefer, but only C. Don't mix. C++ can use C libraries, but so can anything with FFI like Python or Node. That doesn't magically make those C questions. Every C++ question is assumed to include C-type code as a possibility since it's roughly a superset.

Comment: Can you verify that the locale setting changes? Like does the return value of `setlocale()` indicate anything? it's `char*` so you could debug-print that.

Comment: It's worth noting there's a C [`setlocale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) and also C++ [`std::locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) which allows for more reflection and detail.

Comment: @tadman not sure how to debug. I tried but it's not printing anything

Comment: @tadman I read that setlocale is set globally in the program. I guess it should be reset for each event triggered

Comment: `std::locale::global(std::locale("C"));` worked but I see performance issue (its taking 2-3 seconds to print date after date locale change)

Comment: Which part of that is slow? Is it fetching the locale or setting it? You may want to narrow that down. As a note, Windows locale functions may be a lot faster than those using POSIX emulation. If it's just setting the locale that's slow that may not be a problem as users don't normally flip their settings more than a handful of times ever.

Comment: I have no performance issues, the code can get the updated date instantly. You can post the answer to end this thread.